# Why does my flutter ListView.Builder gives renderflex overflowed error?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I am trying to implement a listview builder in my flutter app to generate a scrollable list of reviews, but for some reason its giving me a renderflex overflow error. This doesn't make any sense because a list view is designed to overflow the screen thats what the whole point of it is.

this is the gist of the code I currently have thats giving me the error.

```
return Scaffold(
appBar: HoomeAppBar(context),
body: Column(
children: [
Text('home'),
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 2,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return Container(
width: 200,
height: 300,
child: Column(
children: [
Text(reviews[index].name),
Text(reviews[index].reviewBody),
]
)
)

}
)
]
)
)
```

Comment: Try wrapping your `ListView`with an `Expanded` widget to see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Can you include an image on issue,current snippet should be fine with `shrinkWrap:true`(not recommended btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these two steps:

1. Wrap the ListView.builder inside an Expanded widget.
2. Ensure that the height of the Container widget in your code is enough to contain the reviews.name + reviews.reviewBody.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `ListView` inside `Expanded`

```
return Scaffold(
appBar: HoomeAppBar(context),
body: Column(
    children: [
         Text('home'),
         Expanded (             <- Add it here   
           ListView.builder(
            ...
         )
     ]
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: HoomeAppBar(context),
    body: Column(
        children: [
             Text('home'),
             Expanded (             //Add this widget
               ListView.builder(
                ...
             )
         ]
      )
    );
```

1. Wrap the **`ListView.builder`** inside an **`Expanded`** widget.
2. Remove container `width` & `height` and add column property `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`
   so name & reviews text display with dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

If your Listview.Builder is inside any column(even multiple column) then each column should have wrapped within Expanded widget

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).